# setOnItemClickListener list view from cursor

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Can i set setOnItemClickListener if i can't make list view.setonitemcliclistener because mi xml code is

```
<ListView  
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:cacheColorHint="#666666"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:onClick="verLugarClick"

     />
```

and my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.listatab);

       //Creamos la instancia de DataBaseHelper, un cursor y aplicamos el metodo getNombres al cursor y llamamos al metodo encargado de gestioanr ese cursor
        ayudabbdd = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        Cursor nombresC;     
        nombresC = (Cursor) ayudabbdd.getNombres();  
        nombresC.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(nombresC);
        //Para crear un simpleCursorAdapter necesitamos
        //Contexto this
        //Layour donde se mostrara el resultado, generalmente un textview
        //Cursor 
        //Cual sera el campo que recibiremos de la BBDD
        //Donde tenemos que poner esa informacion, generalmente el ID correspondiente al textvies del layour del segundo parametro
        String[] from = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.CNOMBRE};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.nombreLugar};
        SimpleCursorAdapter lugares = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.entrada_lista, nombresC, from, to);
        setListAdapter(lugares);




      }
```

I have a cursor from a bbdd and to saw the results in a listview i must to set ndroid:id="@android:id/list", and for this i can't use the method findviewbyid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android.R.id.list` to get the `ListView`:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```